# TypeError: XX is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote the following piece of code but it gives an error.
https://jsfiddle.net/5e077ymu/1/

The error is

```
angular.js:14525 TypeError: FirstAncientTheatreFactory.getFirstTheatreDetails is not a function
```

**services.js**

```
.factory('FirstAncientTheatreFactory',function(){
            var firstheatrefact = {};

            var first_ancient_theatre = [
                {
                    "id":0,
                    "description":"The first excavation research, which identified the first ancient theater, took place in 1910 when the then Archbishop of Antiquities, Ap. Arvanitopoulos, revealed part of his stage. At the beginning of the 20th century, over a monument (which was not visible), a street was built and various buildings (houses, workshops, shops) were built, some of which, with their deep foundations, caused irreparable damage to the monument. Since 1977, a systematic effort has been made for the complete disclosure and promotion of the monument with excavations and expropriations of buildings, which continues, from the EO of Prehistoric and Classical Antiquities",
                    "image":"img/first_ancient_theatre/first_ancient_theatre1.jpg"
                }
            ]

            firstheatrefact.getFirstTheatreDetails = function(index){
                return first_ancient_theatre[index];
            }

            return first_ancient_theatre;
        })
        .factory('feedbackFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function ($resource, baseURL) {

            var feedfac = {};

            feedfac.getFeedback = function () {
                return $resource(baseURL + "feedback/:id", null, {'update': {method: 'PUT'}});
            };

            return feedfac;
    }])
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('FirstAncientTheatreController', ['$scope', 'FirstAncientTheatreFactory', function ($scope, FirstAncientTheatreFactory) {

            $scope.message="Loading ...";

            $scope.firstTheatreZero = FirstAncientTheatreFactory.getFirstTheatreDetails(0);



    }])
```

**html page**

```
<div class="container" ng-contoller="FirstAncientTheatreController">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">

                        <p style="font-size:18px;">{{firstTheatreZero.description}}</p>

                    </div>    
                </div>
      </div>
```

I find this a bit weird as the function getFirstTheatreDetails is defined. Did I miss something?

Comment: because you do not return the object with the method.... You return the array

Comment: Change `return first_ancient_theatre;` to `return firstheatrefact;`...

Answer (score 1):

You did `return first_ancient_theatre;`, 
while you should have returned `firstheatrefact` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the json variable instead of the object. Change
`return first_ancient_theatre;` to `return firstheatrefact;`